# ssh negotiation process in ios

Tags: ios, sockets, networking, ssh

Objective : connect to local machine(iPod) to unix server using SSH protocol.

first i have make a socket connection for communication, it is done.

Now the procedure of negotiation with SSH.

```
client to server -> http://@aix.polarhome.com/ssh with port : 775 (using GCDAsyncSocket)
```

on successful connection

```
server to client -> SSH-1.99-OpenSSH-6.6

client to server -> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6

server to client -> list of algo

cleint to server ->
```

this one in code format

```
 if (parsedByteArray[2] == ACK && parsedByteArray[5] == SSH_MSG_KEXINIT) {

        //1 SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
        sendByte[writeIndex++] = SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT;

        [self put32BitInteger:16 toPacket:sendByte fromIndex:writeIndex];
        writeIndex += 4;
        //2 cookie (16 random bytes)
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            sendByte[writeIndex++] = [self random_byte];
        }

        //3 kex_algorithms
        NSString *kex_algorithms = [self kexAlgorithms];
        [self put32BitInteger:kex_algorithms.length toPacket:sendByte fromIndex:writeIndex];
        writeIndex += 4;
        writeIndex = [self convertFromString:kex_algorithms toBytesAndFillArray:sendByte withCurrentIndex:writeIndex];

        //4 server_host_key_algorithms
        NSString *server_host_key_algorithms = [self serverHostKeyAlgorithms];
        [self put32BitInteger:server_host_key_algorithms.length toPacket:sendByte fromIndex:writeIndex];
        writeIndex += 4;
        writeIndex = [self convertFromString:server_host_key_algorithms toBytesAndFillArray:sendByte withCurrentIndex:writeIndex];

        //5 encryption_algorithms_client_to_server
        NSString *encryption_algorithms = [self encryptionAlgorithms];
        [self put32BitInteger:encryption_algorithms.length toPacket:sendByte fromIndex:writeIndex];
        writeIndex += 4;
        writeIndex = [self convertFromString:encryption_algorithms toBytesAndFillArray:sendByte withCurrentIndex:writeIndex];

        //6 encryption_algorithms_server_to_client
        [self put32BitInteger:encryption_algorithms.length toPacket:sendByte fromIndex:writeIndex];
        writeIndex += 4;
        writeIndex = [self convertFromString:encryption_algorithms toBytesAndFillArray:sendByte withCurrentIndex:writeIndex];

        //7 mac_algorithms_client_to_server
        NSString *mac_algorithms = [self macAlgorithms];
        [self put32BitInteger:mac_algorithms.length toPacket:sendByte fromIndex:writeIndex];
        writeIndex += 4;
        writeIndex = [self convertFromString:mac_algorithms toBytesAndFillArray:sendByte withCurrentIndex:writeIndex];

        //8 mac_algorithms_server_to_client
        [self put32BitInteger:mac_algorithms.length toPacket:sendByte fromIndex:writeIndex];
        writeIndex += 4;
        writeIndex = [self convertFromString:mac_algorithms toBytesAndFillArray:sendByte withCurrentIndex:writeIndex];

        //9 compression_algorithms_client_to_server
        NSString *compression_algorithms = [self compressionAlgorithms];
        [self put32BitInteger:compression_algorithms.length toPacket:sendByte fromIndex:writeIndex];
        writeIndex += 4;
        writeIndex = [self convertFromString:compression_algorithms toBytesAndFillArray:sendByte withCurrentIndex:writeIndex];

        //10 compression_algorithms_server_to_client
        [self put32BitInteger:compression_algorithms.length toPacket:sendByte fromIndex:writeIndex];
        writeIndex += 4;
        writeIndex = [self convertFromString:compression_algorithms toBytesAndFillArray:sendByte withCurrentIndex:writeIndex];

        //11 languages_client_to_server
        [self put32BitInteger:0 toPacket:sendByte fromIndex:writeIndex];
        writeIndex += 4;

        //12 languages_server_to_client
        [self put32BitInteger:0 toPacket:sendByte fromIndex:writeIndex];
        writeIndex += 4;

        //13 first_kex_packet_follows
        [self put32BitInteger:1 toPacket:sendByte fromIndex:writeIndex];
        writeIndex += 4;

        sendByte[writeIndex++] = 0; //FALSE

        //14 0 (reserved for future extension) int32
        [self put32BitInteger:0 toPacket:sendByte fromIndex:writeIndex];
        writeIndex += 4;        

        [self sendSSHBinaryPacketPayload:sendByte toLength:writeIndex];
        writeIndex = 0;
    }

-(void)put32BitInteger:(NSInteger)val toPacket:(Byte *)packet fromIndex:(int)index{
    //parse int value from 32 bit to 4 bytes and assign to packet.

    Byte bArray[4];
    bArray[3] = val;
    bArray[2] = val >> 8;
    bArray[1] = val >> 16;
    bArray[0] = val >> 24;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        packet[index + i] = bArray[i];
    }
}

//SSH Encryption Algorithms
-(NSString *)kexAlgorithms{
    return @"diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1";
}

-(NSString *)serverHostKeyAlgorithms{
    return @"ssh-rsa";
}

-(NSString *)encryptionAlgorithms{
    return @"aes256-ctr";
}

-(NSString *)macAlgorithms{
    return @"hmac-sha2-256";
}

-(NSString *)compressionAlgorithms{
    return @"none";
}

-(NSString *)languageAlgorithms{
    return @"none";
}

server to client -> Packet corrupted.
```

Please suggest me, is it right way. What corrections i need to implement.

Things that i am not clear about are
1. version string is first negotiated from server or client. Here the server sending it and 
2. Do i need to send key exchange data as plain or with BPP (Binary Packet Protocol).

Please help me.

Comment: Are you implementing the SSH protocol from scratch? You should be referring to the SSH RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4253).

Comment: Yes, we are using the same RFC but not getting it right. you can refer our code and suggest changes.

Comment: @Kenster can you give me sample code that help me.

Comment: Read CFNetworking and Security Framework. it will solve your problem

Comment: Hello.. You can do SSH Handshaking from both sides.

Answer (score 0):

1) I was doing something similar for a side project not too long ago. I found this book to be very helpful when trying to implement/understand the handshaking process:

> **Implementing SSL / TLS Using Cryptography and PKI** 
>   *by Joshua Davies*

That book offers great sample code and advice.

2) I noticed in the sample code you posted, is you seem to have a lot of helper functions written in Objective-C, you may have a much easier time increasing the readability of your code if you implement your helper functions in plain C. You also should be using structs to hold the data structure for the packets, it will make your life easier.

3) Based off the sample code you posted, its hard to offer you help with what is going wrong, can you post a gist or something with a more complete snippet.